# Дообучение YOLO V8

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Можно ли дообучить уже обученную модель YOLO V8?
Обучал на пользовательских данных пару дней. Хочется добавить в уже обученную модель обнаружение других объектов, и не очень хочется тратить лишнее время на обучение модели тому, что она и так знает.
Подскажите, как мне это сделать?

Comment: Уважаемый @Захар, у них в документации всё про это написано. Потрудитесь ознакомиться. Сам пользуюсь, читаю, есть их форум...
https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/train/

Answer (score 0):

Данный вопрос гуглится по первой ссылке в интернете, вот к примеру отличная статья с хабра: https://habr.com/ru/articles/714232/

Официальная документация: https://docs.ultralytics.com/ru/modes/train/

Comment: я спрашивал другое, перечитайте, пожалуйста, мой вопрос, если бы я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос в оф документации или на форумах не полез бы задавать вопрос